# Find a sequence number with more than one occurrence and return the data in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do a query that when finds a sequence number with more than one occurrence and day (day0 to day d62) returns the data in the same row. For example the sequence number 939860789 occurs in 8 days but each data are in a different row and I need all the data of this sequence number stays in the same row of d0/5770 that is the first occurrence.

[Image with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrzsB.jpg)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('test01..#TestSample') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE #TestSample;

CREATE TABLE #TestSample 
(    
    seq_number CHAR(9), 
    d0 VARCHAR(6), d1 VARCHAR(6), d2 VARCHAR(6), d3 VARCHAR(6), 
    d4 VARCHAR(6), d5 VARCHAR(6), d6 VARCHAR(6), d7 VARCHAR(6), 
    d8 VARCHAR(6), d9 VARCHAR(6), d10 VARCHAR(6), d11 VARCHAR(6), 
    d12 VARCHAR(6), d13 VARCHAR(6), d14 VARCHAR(6), d15 VARCHAR(6), 
    d16 VARCHAR(6), d17 VARCHAR(6), d18 VARCHAR(6), d19 VARCHAR(6), 
    d20 VARCHAR(6)
)

INSERT INTO #TestSample (seq_number, d0)
    VALUES ('939860783', '632'), 
           ('939860785', '6851'), 
           ('939860789', '5770'), 
           ('939860789', 'V4579'),  
           ('939860789', '4019'), 
           ('939860789', '2867'), 
           ('939860789', '25000'), 
           ('939860789', '2722'), 
           ('939860789', '42731'), 
           ('939860789', 'V5861')

SELECT seq_number, 
       d0 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 0 THEN d0 ELSE NULL END),
       d1 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN d0 ELSE NULL END),
       d2 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN d0 ELSE NULL END),
       d3 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN d0 ELSE NULL END)
FROM (SELECT seq_number, d0,
             rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY seq_number ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 

      FROM #TestSample    
     ) d   
GROUP BY d.seq_number
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no correlation between the question and the example. E.g. where is the date column that indicates that `sequence number 939860789 occurs in 8 days` and why the column in the example is called `d0`?

Answer (score 0):

You are totally on the right track.  How about putting the values into another table?

```
SELECT seq_number, 
       d0 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 0 THEN d0 ELSE NULL END),
       d1 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN d0 ELSE NULL END),
       d2 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN d0 ELSE NULL END),
       d3 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN d0 ELSE NULL END)
INTO #new_TestSample
FROM (SELECT seq_number, d0,
             rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY seq_number ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 

      FROM #TestSample    
     ) d   
GROUP BY d.seq_number;
```